# Return data to jquery/ajax call from entity framework object in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework

I am trying to get `List<Product>` from Entity Framework using jquery/ajax call. Here's the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchService.asmx/search",
            data: "{'lookup':'itemName'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (products) {
                // Just printing the result for now.
                console.log(products);
            }
        });
```

Search method in web service is implemented as:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Product> search(string lookup)
{
    using (eCommerceDBEntities context = new eCommerceDBEntities())
    {
        List<Product> pr = context.Products.Where(i => i.ProductName.Contains(lookup)).ToList();
        return pr;
    }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting a 500 (Internal server error) in the console log.

To my surprise, the following code works:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Product> search(string lookup)
{
    using (eCommerceDBEntities context = new eCommerceDBEntities())
    {
        List<Product> pr = context.Products.Where(i => i.ProductName.Contains(lookup)).ToList();
        return new List<Product> {new Product(){
            ProductName="abc", ProductPrice=123},
            new Product(){
                ProductName ="xyz", ProductPrice=321
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Above hardcoded `List<Product>` returns a nice object, but the one where I query from database doesn't. I would have assumed it's the same thing whether it's hardcoded or queried form DB.

I am trying this approach for the first time so I might be doing something horribly wrong here. How do I get the data from DB?

Comment: Don't you need a 'Select' as part of that query??

Comment: @Nanda: I'm using lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting 500 looks like you have some exceptions into server side. Can you find out where exception occurs and what stacktrace you got? Try to check types compatibility between `Product` and `context.Products`.

```
List<Product> pr = context.Products.Where(i => i.ProductName.Contains(lookup)).ToList();
```

Also you may check `lookup` value for correct parsing from client-side.

```
public List<Product> search(string lookup)
```

And Contains() for valid variable.

```
i => i.ProductName.Contains(lookup)
```

Comment: I can't seem to find any exceptions. Product and context.Products is indeed compatible as I have used them in other methods successfully. Parsing of lookup is fine to my knowledge, I even tried hardcoding the lookup value to see if there were any parsing problems, same result.

Answer (score 0):

try using these attributes over your web method.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

it should work.

Also you need to check for the output of the lambda expression.

### Edit -1

As your service taking string as parameter so change to `contentType` to string and check.

 You can also remove it from your jQuery ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "searchService.asmx/search",
        data: "{'lookup':'itemName'}",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (products) {
            // Just printing the result for now.
            console.log(products);
          }
      });
```

Comment: I added those as you suggested but still getting 505. I have checked lambda expression output and it seems to be fine. Thanks.

Comment: change contentType to string and check.

Comment: That didn't work. Even if we leave the ajax POST part alone and I hardcode the lookup value as `List<Product> pr = context.Products.Where(i => i.ProductName.Contains("a")).ToList();` I get 505. Thanks for your response.